# Fade_in effect stopped working after changing theme to NoTitleBar (in manifest)

Tags: android, xml, fadein

I am designing a splash screen for my app which I'm working on from last 1 month.
i have added an image in an xml file and applied a fade_in effect to it using fade_in.xml .. but one strange thing i noticed is that fade_in works perfectly when using the AppTheme but stops working when i changed the theme to **NoTitleBar** using the below line of code:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

(Inside the Manifest.xml)

I need to put this in the manifest...can't remove it ...Any solution will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace it with

```js
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

OR

Use the app theme and change the code to

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActionBar().hide();
```

OR use below code for reference

```js
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class Splash extends Activity {

 @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
  this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.splash);
  Thread loading = new Thread() {
   public void run() {
    try {
     sleep(1000);
     startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
     finish();
    }
   }
  };
  loading.start();
 }
}
```

`

Comment: You are a LifeSaver ..you know that. I am really very very very Thankful to you.....now its working just as i wanted.

Comment: the first method ...replacing with android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" worked for me